# Get current page number of splitted article

Tags: paged

I am trying to find a way to get the current page number of an article that has been splitted into several pages with the use of:

```
<!-- nextpage -->
```

There is an example that can be found here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#Testing_for_paginated_Pages

But this doesn't work for me – it always returns 0:

```
$paged = $wp_query->get( 'paged' );
echo $paged;
```

Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: If one of the answers helps you, select it as the answer please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For multi-page posts:

- The `$page` global variable returns the current page of a multi-page post.
- The `$numpages` global variable returns the total number of pages in a multi-page post.

For paginated archive index pages:

- The `$paged` global variable returns the current page number of a paginated archive index.

To use any of these variables, simply *globalize* them first:

```
global $page;

echo 'The current page number of this post is ' . $page . '.';
```

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
$queryVars = $wp_query->query_vars;
    $pageNum = ($queryVars[page]);

    if($pageNum) { 
        echo "Page n&deg;" . $pageNum; 
    } else { 
        echo "Page n&deg;1";
    }
```

Tested with wp 3.2 with basic permalinks and custom.

Edit: Didn't see Chip Bennett's answer wich is smaller.